# Render PyImGUI into an already existing window

Tags: python, user-interface, render

I was wondering if there was a way to render a pyimgui window or windows into an existing window, in this case a game, like ImGUI from c++ can do so. I really like the gui that both give, yet I'm still trying to understand the doc from pyimgui, so i wanted to know that in advance to see if I keep on reading or just find something else that allows me to render on an existing window.

Hopefully i'm making some sense.

By what I've gathered so far, the only "rendering backends" that could help are sdl2 and glfw, but then again, I don't know if it's actually possible as i still don't know how they work.